# how to correctly map a Set<Entity> on a POJO using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, set, persistence

I'm trying to tie into my `User` class a `Set` to store profiles for each user. I fiddled a bit and am a little lost now. The set part of my `User` class is currently defined as:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = UserProfile.class)
@JoinTable(name = "HRM_USER_USER_PROFILE", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_user") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_profile") })
@Column(name = "id_profile")
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<String> userProfiles = new HashSet<String>(0);
```

I know I'm using a different type in the Set. That's because the `UserProfile` is defined as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="HRM_USER_PROFILE")
public class UserProfile extends BasePojo {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="type", length=15, unique=true, nullable=false)
    private UserProfileType type;

    public UserProfileType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(UserProfileType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
```

Where UserProfileType is an enum declared as:

```
public enum UserProfileType {

    USER("USER"),
    DBA("DBA"),
    ADMIN("ADMIN");

    String userProfileType;

    private UserProfileType(String userProfileType){
        this.userProfileType = userProfileType;
    }

    public String getUserProfileType(){
        return userProfileType;
    }
```

I know this is something related to the annotation `@ElementCollection`. But I'm rather confused.

Where am I wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-enum-type-mapping-example   >>try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this >>>

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) //enum type mapping with String Values
@Column(name="type", length=15, unique=true, nullable=false)
private UserProfileType type;
```

you can also use `ordinal` value for if type is Numerical Values

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) //enum type mapping with ordinal Values
@Column(name="type", length=15, unique=true, nullable=false)
private UserProfileType type;
```

Comment: I'm getting a `java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method setType(UserProfileType) in the type UserProfile is not applicable for the arguments (String)`. Will try with `EnumType.ORDINAL` now.

Comment: Post your complete dto.. you have posted code is splitted .. please do it

Comment: posted with your suggestions.

Comment: try this    http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-enum-type-mapping-example

Comment: I have tried using the `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` annotation on the getter for UserProfile and UserProfileType. No luck. I removed the annotation and am now getting an `org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of b.c.m.h.m.UserProfile.id` and, a little below, it reads `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@...`.

Comment: okk thanks .. atleast one problem is resolved .. now make sense bcoz there may be a problem with mapping